# Schemas and transactions for filesystems

Tags: transactions, filesystems, schema, acid

There are two standard ways to store your data: a database or on a filesystem. Between these, the database has at least two advantages for maintaining the integrity of your data:

- Schemas: we can declare the intended structure of the data and have a guarantee that the data satisfies this structure
- Transactionality with full ACID properties

Are there any filesystems, or filesystem managers on top of filesystems, that provide these key features?

I imagine, for example, a program which manages data in one directory, the schema for which I provide, and through which I issue CRUD instructions to update this directory, using transactions to ensure atomicity.

The schema might, for example, be defined inductively, e.g.

```
root ::= { pdfcontainer }
pdfcontainer ::= { pdf }
pdf(f) ::= isfile && suffix == 'pdf'
```

After which the instruction `CREATE /container1/image.jpg <contents>` would fail because `/container1` no longer satisfies `pdfcontainer` which means `/` no longer satisfies `root`.